# in Java do i need to mark an int field as volatile if threads increment it only within synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, volatile

in Java do i need to mark an int field as volatile if threads increment it only within synchronized method?

And no other usage of the field.

Thanks

Comment: So you never read the field?

Comment: No, you need not.